# How to put these codes to Angular2 Component

Tags: templates, angular, components, repeat

HTML Code:

```
  <ul class="arc">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="important"><a href="#">URL1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">URL2</a></li>
    <li class="other">&nbsp;</li>
  </ul>
```

Angular2 Code:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'arc-list',
      template: `
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li *ngFor="arclink of arclinks"><a href="{{arclink.url}}" title="{{arclink.title}}">
           {{arclink.description}}</a>
           </li>
          </ul>
      `
    })
    export class ArcList {
      arclinks = [
        {"url":"#", "description":"Home", "title":"TitleHome", "class":"active"}, 
        {"url":"#", "description":"URL1", "title":"Title1", "class":"important"}, 
        {"url":"#", "description":"URL2", "title":"Title2", "class":""},
        {"url":"", "description":"other", "title":"other", "class":"other"}
      ]
    }
```

How can I write the component code to let the component ***generate the same thing as the HTML Code***?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `arclinks` are set as property of your component and use `*ngFor="let arclink of arclinks"` (note `let` keyword):

```javascript
@Component({
  selector: 'arc-list',
  template: `
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li *ngFor="let arclink of arclinks">
          <a href="{{arclink.url}}" title="{{arclink.title}}">{{arclink.description}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  `
})
export class ArcList {
  arclinks = [
    {"url":"#", "description":"Link1", "title":"Title1", "class":"active"}, 
    {"url":"#", "description":"Link1", "title":"Title1", "class":""}, 
    {"url":"#", "description":"Link1", "title":"Title1", "class":""}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know how to output the class="active" in <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>. also how to output the <li>&nbsp;</li>?

Comment: On what condition you decide that item is "active"? As for `<li>&nbsp;</li>` just add it after `<li *ngFor="let arclink of arclinks">...</li><li>&nbsp;</li>`.

Comment: When "class":"active" in the array, the class should be output. When there is no URL and description, the item should be like '<li>&nbsp;</li>'. Thank you so much for your reply.